# Block Range of IPs

Tags: .htaccess, ip, block

I'm trying to block a range of IPs from visiting my website

Here is what I have in my .htaccess file

```
order allow,deny
Deny from 64.244.0.0/64.245.255.255
Deny from 64.244.0.0/15
allow from all
```

I'd like to know if anyone can tell (or estimate) me how many IPs have i blocked there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the first DENY FROM is just wrong.  I've always seen it this way

```
    64.244.0.0/15
Base Address^  ^Number of bits to use for subnet
```

This would mean that you have 2^15 addresses in the deny block.

*Edit*

Using the comments below, what you would want is

```
ORDER deny,allow
DENY from 64.244.0.0/15
ALLOW from all
```

Comment: So what are the disadvantages of me doing it the way I am now? It's not working? Incorrect? Or am I blocking more IPs now than I would using your method?

Comment: I've never seen a deny block written the way you have it written on the second line.  If I'm correct and that is wrong, then the server probably won't be able to parse it and will just give up reading the config file.

Comment: I believe I misled you before.  If you want to block all IP addresses from 64.244.0.0 to 64.245.255.255 then you could just do 64.244.0.0/15 and it will only block all IP addresses that start with the same 15 bits at the 64.244.0.0 (in this case, any IPs that are 64.[244|245].*.*)

Comment: now that I think about it, I can also do 'Deny from 64.244' which basically denies 64.244.*.*  Correct?